# IntelliJ: Jump to declaration in node modules when TypeScript community stubs are present?

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, npm

In IntelliJ (and WebStorm), when working on a JavaScript project (React, NPM), you can have the IDE download TypeScript community stubs in `Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`. They allow the editor to provide **Parameter info** to you.

However, when enabled, `Go To | (Type) Declaration` or `Go To | Implementation(s)` always jumps to the library's corresponding `index.d.ts` file in `External Libraries | @types` - which isn't
exactly useful when you are looking for documentation, comments, or implementation details.

Is there a way to support **Parameter info** but at the same time jump to the right location in `node_modules/` when using the `Go To` context menu command (or make the **Quick Documentation** work)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current behavior depends on a way `d.ts` files are defined and included.

- type definitions, if available, are always used for completion
- If type definitions are installed in the `@types` folder, IDE will try to navigate to the JavaScript sources of the library when using **Navigate | Declaration**. Please note that this only works for symbols that are defined as classes, variables or functions (and not interfaces or types) in the `.d.ts` file. If all symbols in `d.ts` are defined as types or interfaces, that makes it impossible to map them to the actual code.
- If type definitions are available inside the module (included in npm module distribution), IDE will not index the JavaScript sources by default and, thus, will not be able to navigate to them. To index these files, please use **Navigate | Implementation** first and answer **Yes** when the question pops up:

[image]

Comment: Yay, it works! But: If one accidentally clicked No there, is there a way to revise that decision? In other words, where's that setting hiding in the preferences? :-)

Comment: when you press *Yes*, `<option name="includedJSSourcePackages">` is written to `.idea/workspace.xml`. If you press *No*, nothing is written anywhere, and you will get the same prompt on next **Navigate | Implementation** action call